# How can we use MySQL select statement with group_concat and case condition?

Tags: mysql, case, group-concat

I wrote mysql select statement with group_concat and I can get the correct result. But, if I modify my select statement with case dondition, I couldn't get the corret result. My select statement as follows:

```
SELECT replace(concat(concat(complex_check_name, '='), res_string), ',', '') results FROM 
(SELECT cc.NAME complex_check_name, group_concat(concat(concat(concat(concat(concat(f.NAME, ';') , sgk.NAME),' ') ,cc.operator),' ')) as res_string
FROM complex_check_anag cc,lnksinglechecktocomplexcheck lk,single_check_anag sgk,functionalci f ,lnkciitemtocomplexcheck lkcg 
WHERE cc.complex_check_id = lk.complex_check_id AND sgk.single_check_id = lk.single_check_id and f.id = lkcg.config_item_id 
and cc.complex_check_id = lkcg.compx_check_id GROUP BY cc.NAME) x
```

with this select statement , I can get the following result:

```
checks CO04=INFRAVICO04;cpu check CO04 and INFRAVICO04;disk check CO04 and INFRAVICO04;mem check CO04 and 
checks CO05=INFRAVICO05;cpu check CO05 or INFRAVICO05;disk check CO05 or INFRAVICO05;mem check CO05 or 
checks DB01=INFRASEPDB01;mem check DB01 and INFRASEPDB01;cpu check DB01 and INFRASEPDB01;disk check DB01 and
```

I want to replace the "and" with "&", "or" with "||" in the result; the value is in the field of "cc.operator" . So, I have modified the previous select statement as follows:

```
SELECT replace(concat(concat(complex_check_name, '='), res_string), ',', '') results FROM 
(SELECT cc.NAME complex_check_name, group_concat(concat(concat(concat(concat(concat(f.NAME, ';') , sgk.NAME),' ') ,
CASE cc.operator when 'and'  then '&' when 'or' then '||' END CASE),' ')) as res_string 
FROM complex_check_anag cc,lnksinglechecktocomplexcheck lk,single_check_anag sgk,functionalci f ,lnkciitemtocomplexcheck lkcg 
WHERE cc.complex_check_id = lk.complex_check_id AND sgk.single_check_id = lk.single_check_id and f.id = lkcg.config_item_id 
and cc.complex_check_id = lkcg.compx_check_id GROUP BY cc.NAME) x
```

But,there is an error message, I couldn't get the correct result . could you give some suggestions for me , please ?
I really appreciate for your help !

Comment: what does the error message say?

Comment: If its just replace then why not modify the first query as `replace(replace(replace(concat(concat(complex_check_name, '='), res_string), ',', ''),'and','&'),'or','||') results `

Comment: @JaakKütt , the error message is "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE),' ')) as res_string 
FROM complex_check_anag cc,lnksinglechecktocomplexche' at line 3 "                    thanks a lot

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty, no I cann't use the "replace" key word in the sql statment , because if the reuslt includes some words with "or" (like: port number check), "replace" will not work properly. thanks !

Comment: @JaakKütt , yes when statements cover all the cases ; I also modified as : CASE cc.operator when 'and'  then '&' when 'or' then '||' ELSE NULL END CASE . But, it doesn't work . Thanks !

Comment: well in that case you may use something as `replace('example or origin',' or ', ' || ')`.. i.e. one space before and after the word ?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty, yes you are right, in this way it works correctly. But, I want to know whether we can use "case" and " group_concat " in the same sql statement .Thanks .

Comment: Well case when is possible but your query is a bit complex and with some sample data and table structure it could be validated.

Comment: might this make a difference? CASE expression (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html) vs CASE statement (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) try the expression syntax with just "end" not "end case" (sorry, had them links mixed up in prev comment)